# Cancel a file download/request on node.js http.Client based on file size

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a function on node.js to start a file download but I want to create a rule where the function checks the file size before downloading the data.

I got the response headers and checked the size but I dont know how to cancel everything withou transferring the actual data/body. Maybe there is a way to transfer only the headers first and the, if match my rule, I can fire another request to do the download.

Here is a fragment of my code:

```
request.on('response', function(response) {
        var filesize = response.headers['content-length'];
        console.log("File size " + filename + ": " + filesize + " bytes.");
        response.pause();
        if (filesize >= 50000) {
            // WHAT TO PUT HERE TO CANCEL THE DOWNLOAD?
            console.log("Download cancelled. File too big.");
        } else {
            response.resume();
        }
        //Create file and write the data chunks to it
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to HTTP protocol specifications [9.4 HEAD](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4)

> The HEAD method is identical to GET
> except that the server MUST NOT return
> a message-body in the response. The
> metainformation contained in the HTTP
> headers in response to a HEAD request
> SHOULD be identical to the information
> sent in response to a GET request.
> This method can be used for obtaining
> metainformation about the entity
> implied by the request without
> transferring the entity-body itself.
> This method is often used for testing
> hypertext links for validity,
> accessibility, and recent
> modification.
>
> The response to a HEAD request MAY be
> cacheable in the sense that the
> information contained in the response
> MAY be used to update a previously
> cached entity from that resource. If
> the new field values indicate that the
> cached entity differs from the current
> entity (as would be indicated by a
> change in Content-Length, Content-MD5,
> ETag or Last-Modified), then the cache
> MUST treat the cache entry as stale.

If your server does not response properly to this I think you might be out of luck?
Next simply just use `google.request('HEAD'` instead of `google.request('GET'`

---

## Some code

I tested the following below.
fake.js is just a fake server using express to test.

**fake.js:**

```
var HOST = 'localhost';
var PORT = 3000;
var connections = 0;
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

if (process.argv[2] && process.argv[3]) {
    HOST = process.argv[2];
    PORT = process.argv[3];
}

app.use(express.staticProvider(__dirname + '/public'));

// to reconnect.
app.get('/small', function(req,  res) {
    console.log(req.method);
    if (req.method == 'HEAD') {
        console.log('here');
        res.send('');
    } else {
        connections++;
        res.send('small');    
    }
});

app.get('/count', function(req, res) {
    res.send('' + connections);
});

app.get('/reset', function(req, res) {
    connections = 0;
    res.send('reset');
});


if (!module.parent) {
    app.listen(PORT, HOST);
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d", app.address().port)
}
```

test.js is to test head from http-client.
**test.js:**

```
var http = require('http');
var google = http.createClient(3000, 'localhost');
var request = google.request('HEAD', '/small',
  {'host': 'localhost'});
request.end();
request.on('response', function (response) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
  response.setEncoding('utf8');
});
```

---

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/node/stackoverflow/4832362$ curl http://localhost:3000/count
0
```

---

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/node/stackoverflow/4832362$ node test.js 
STATUS: 200
HEADERS: {"content-type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","content-length":"0","connection":"close"}
```

---

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/node/stackoverflow/4832362$ curl http://localhost:3000/count
0
```

As you can see still 0.